# How to add HttpOnly and Secure flags to lighttpd server?

Tags: cookies, lighttpd, httponly

I am using lighttpd server (version 1.4.53) along with FastCGI. I have a C++ code handling CGI process. I want to add `HttpOnly` and `Secure` flags for all my cookies. The `Set-Cookie` header is being set from the C++ code when creating the responses like this:

```
string sHeader = "Set-Cookie: " + sCookieName + " = " + sCookieValue + "; SameSite=Strict; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure\n";
```

This does not work as the pages do not render and show a weird "undefined" error on the page. I read about `mod_usertrack`. Is it needed to be used in lighttpd server modules list for these flags to work? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

> Or am I missing something here?

Yes.  If you are generating the response, then this has little to do with lighttpd.  While lighttpd is able to manipulate requests and responses (mod_setenv, mod_magnet, mod_usertrack, etc), lighttpd does not do so (beyond HTTP RFCs compliance) unless lighttpd is configured to do so.

> This does not work as the pages do not render and show a weird "undefined" error on the page.

Your problem is somewhere in your code.  You are probably not generating a valid page.  Use your browser debugging tools to see the HTTP response headers and to see the XML or HTML response body that you are returning to the client.  Alternatively, use a command line tool for the client, e.g. `curl -v ...`

Comment: Thank you. I found that the issue was "HttpOnly" flag. When I was enabling it, the cookie was not accessible from my client-side javascript and hence the undefined error!